# How to get file ownership i.e lines of code added by each developer per commit for an application

Tags: git

I tried below statement

git blame --line-porcelain file | sed -n 's/^author //p' |sort | uniq -c | sort -rn

but this statement gives for the latest commit . I need for each and every commit for a particular file.

Please suggest !!

Comment: Generally this is impossible, as if a developer replaced some line, he will get the changes for that line, but overwrites the changes that another developer did to that line before. At least the output is no simple list but a multidimensional graph. You don't want to see such thing in a single stream of terminal output. Of course you can loop through each commit for a file and then blame each commit as you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sequence

```
git log --reverse --oneline filename | awk '{ print $1; }'| while read c
do echo "authors for commit $c:"
    git blame --line-porcelain filename $c | grep "^author " | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
done
```

As I told you: This is a multi dimensional thing with coordinates `(filename, commit, author, number of lines)`. First think about how you want to display or store the output. Also note that `git blame` is not about **added** lines but changed lines. So if someone deleted a file with 10k lines, he/she will get noted as a changer of 10k lines, though the statement was just `rm file`.

Number of Lines changed is generally a very bad parameter to measure code or work done on some code. Sometimes an author that thinks a week over his code and then changes one line, improving the speed of the program by a factor of 1000 is a much worthier author than this guy last week, who wrote 5000 lines of spagetthi code.

But this information is redundant. Better use

```
git log -p --reverse filename
```

and learn to read patch files.

Comment: Similarily can we find the Line of code per commit for a file

wc -l filename 

will give for a file , but i need it at commit level for a file

Comment: I use such `while read` loops nearly every day. They are very useful and general.

Comment: can we find the Line of code per commit for a file wc -l filename will give for a file , but i need it at commit level for a file